# Can S Health data be accessed online?

Tags: applications, samsung, sync

Is it possible to access S Health data online through a Samsung or other account?  If I log in at account.samsung.com, I see an S Health section. However, it is not clickable. This made me suspect that I somehow need to enable syncing before the data becomes available online.  But I cannot find any such setting within the app.  I *am* logged in within the app.  I use a Samsung S7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access S Health data online, only via the S Health app.